# how to write a query by including the null values too

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT sum(cash)  from bought_cash WHERE uid=1 AND source NOT IN ('a', 'b')
```

gives the result as `140`

and

```
 SELECT sum(cash)  from bought_cash WHERE uid=1 AND source  IN ('a', 'b')
```

gives `NULL`

and

```
SELECT sum(cash)  from bought_cash WHERE uid=1
```

gives result as `240`

and

```
SELECT sum(cash)  from bought_cash WHERE uid=1 and source is null
```

gives result as `100`

How do I write a query so that the first query gives result as `240` by including the null values.

Comment: Are you sure it should be the result of 240.  I see no reason why this would not be correct.

Comment: did you mean that you want the `NULL` value to be in your first query ?

Comment: in the first query iam not including the null values in where clause so the result should include the null values right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try also next:

```
select sum(cash) 
from bought_cash
where uid = 1 and (source is null or source not in ('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: thanks that works. but why doesnt it include the null values by default?

Comment: because null values are sign for missing values, by sql standard, and when you include null in your IN criteria, NULL become unknown values

Comment: Actually it is included by default, but as for the SUM operation, you are adding a NULL, which does not contain any value. Its like 1 + Null = 1

Comment: null here is a source and not the cash

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select sum(cash) from bought_cash 
    where uid=1 and isnull(source, 'c') not in ('a', 'b')
```

this should map null entries to the value 'c', which isn't 'a' or 'b', so should be included in the result set.